# Blazor Wasm - Change @Body starting page to reference an RCL page

Tags: razor, components, blazor, webassembly

I have a Razor Wasm Project which references a RazorComponentLibrary (RLC) project. In RLC I want to have an Index.razor page with `@page "/"` directive.
When in a Layout (which is also in RLC) I add the `@Body` directive, the browser **shows the right layout** but with the `NotFound` page instead of the Index.razor one. This might also mean I can't use any pages...
Can I make this work somehow?

When creating the RLC project I did enable pages and areas.
I am referencing the RLC project and also able to use components.

Comment: In app.razor the `<Router  />` has a parameter called `AdditionalAssemblies` did you use that?

Comment: You should *not* enable "Pages and Areas" for a Blazor RCL and you should do what Brian said.